# Covariance Matrix vs. Pairwise Covariance Matrix?

Tags: r, covariance, matrix

I found this equation [here](http://jonathantemplin.com/files/multivariate/mv12psyc943/mv12psyc943_lecture11.pdf) to calculate a covariance matrix of any number of variables using matrix algebra.
$$\frac1{N} (X - 1\bar{x})^T(X - 1\bar{x}^T)
$$
For a given matrix $X$ with $N$ samples.  The following is SAS code I have found in the link above.

```
ONES = J(N, 1, 1);
meanvec = (1/N)*t(X)*ONES;
mean_matrix = ONES*t(meanvec);
cov_matrix = (1/n) * t(X- mean_matrix) * (x - mean_matrix);
```

However, I don't have SAS on my workstation so I converted this to R which is nearly identical.

```
ONES <- matrix(1, nrow=N, ncol=1)
meanvec <- (1/N) * t(X) %*% ONES
mean_matrix <- ONES %*% t(meanvec)
cov_matrix <- (1/N) * t(X - mean_matrix) %*% (X - mean_matrix)
```

Now, here is where I run in to problems.  Let's take this sample matrix $X$

```
X
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   90   60   90
[2,]   90   90   30
[3,]   60   60   60
[4,]   60   60   90
[5,]   30   30   30
```

If I run the above code I get the following covariance matrix.

```
cov_matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  504  360  180
[2,]  360  360    0
[3,]  180    0  720
```

But when I run the `cov` function from the `stats` package I get

```
cov(X)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  630  450  225
[2,]  450  450    0
[3,]  225    0  900
```

which are the pairwise covariances between columns (verified by `cov(X[,1], X[,1])`.  Sorry if I am missing some basic math concept here but what is the difference here?  Why would I see 'returns a covariance' matrix from two things that return different 'kinds' of covariance matrices?

This is strictly a learning concept for me so I would appreciate any further information you could provide to help me understand these differences.

Comment: Use $(N-1)$ in place of $N$ to obtain the so-called "unbiased" version

Comment: @rvl, Hah! So it is, that gets the numbers to match.  Why would one want either 'unbiased' or 'biased' versions though?  I was not aware there was such a distinction.

Comment: See (1) the help page for `cov`; (2) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100041; and (3) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3931 for intuition. For yet more information search [standard deviation correction](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=standard+deviation+correction).

Comment: Thanks whuber, @rvl if you add your answer below I will accept it.

Comment: A covariance matrix *is* just a matrix of pairwise covariances, so I'm not sure about the distinction you're making.

Comment: @dsaxton, I was unaware of the $N-1$ component.  The formula I had used wasn't for the "unbiased" version which led to the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments:

> A covariance matrix is just a matrix of pairwise covariances, so I'm
>   not sure about the distinction you're making.

– dsaxton

> Use $N−1$ in place of $N$ to obtain the so-called "unbiased" version

– rvl

> See (1) the help page for `cov`; (2)
>   [How exactly did statisticians agree to using (n-1) as the unbiased estimator for population variance without simulation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100041/how-exactly-did-statisticians-agree-to-using-n-1-as-the-unbiased-estimator-for);
>   and (3)
>   [Intuitive explanation for dividing by $n-1$ when calculating standard deviation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/intuitive-explanation-for-dividing-by-n-1-when-calculating-standard-deviation)
>   for intuition. For yet more information search [standard deviation
>   correction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=standard+deviation+correction+answers%3A1).

– whuber