# wrong variance shown in R

Tags: r, variance

when i am trying to find a variance of a sample (10,20,30) in R with below command

```
var(c(10,20,30))
```

it's showing 100. I believe it should be 66.66667

Comment: It's the *sample* variance, not the *population* variance. So it is divided by $n - 1$, not $n$.

Comment: Yes 200/2 =100 as compared to 200/3 =66.667. The difference between these two estimates of variance is small when the sample size is large.  The division by n-1 is done to get an unbiased estimate of the population variance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the documentation (`?var`):

> The denominator $n - 1$ is used which gives an unbiased estimator of the
>   (co)variance for i.i.d. observations.

That this "degrees-of-freedom correction" yields an unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$ is for example discussed in [How exactly did statisticians agree to using (n-1) as the unbiased estimator for population variance without simulation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100041/how-exactly-did-statisticians-agree-to-using-n-1-as-the-unbiased-estimator-for).

What you have in mind is the population variance of a discrete random variable with three possible outcomes (or, alternatively, the ML estimator of $\sigma^2$).

The standardization you prefer is for example incorporated in the moments package:

```
library(moments)
moment(c(10,20,30), order = 2, central = T)
```