# Confusion regarding proof that the variance estimator is unbiased for finite population

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimators, unbiased-estimator, survey-sampling, finite-population

Going through Sharon L. Lohr's Sampling design book (2nd Edition), I have no issues with the content all the way until it goes into the proof in chapter 2 on SRSWOR that $E[s^2] = S^2$, where $S^2$ is defined as:
$$
S^2 = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_i - \bar{y}_{U})^2
$$
And the sample variance estimator is:
$$
s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}(y_i-\bar{y})^2
$$
where $U$ is the index set of the finite population:
$$
U = \{1,2,\dotsc,N\}
$$
And $\mathcal{S}$ is the particular sample chosen, a subset consisting of $n$ of the units in $U$.

It says:

> and then find the multiplicative constant that will give the unbiasedness:
> $$
> \begin{align}
> E\left[\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}(y_i-\bar{y})^2\right] & = E\left[\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}((y_i-\bar{y}_U) - (\bar{y}-\bar{y}_U))^2\right]\\
> & = E\left[\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}(y_i-\bar{y}_U)^2 - n(\bar{y}-\bar{y}_U)^2\right]\\
> & = E\left[\sum_{i=1}^NZ_i(y_i-\bar{y}_U)^2\right] - n\textrm{Var}(\bar{y})\\
> & = \frac{n}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(y_i-\bar{y}_U)^2-\left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right)S^2\\
> & = \frac{n(N-1)}{N}S^2 - \frac{N-n}{N}S^2\\
> & = (n-1)S^2
> \end{align}
> $$
> Thus,
> $$
> E\left[\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}(y_i-\bar{y})^2\right] = E[s^2] = S^2
> $$

I have no issues with most of the derivation, except for how the first line turns into the second line.
I assume there must be the intermediary step:
$$
\begin{align}
E\left[\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}(y_i-\bar{y})^2\right] & = E\left[\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}((y_i-\bar{y}_U) - (\bar{y}-\bar{y}_U))^2\right]\\
& = E\left[\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}(y_i-\bar{y}_U)^2 - \sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}(\bar{y}-\bar{y}_U)^2\right]\\
& = E\left[\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}(y_i-\bar{y}_U)^2 - n(\bar{y}-\bar{y}_U)^2\right]\\
\end{align}
$$
But I still can't get from the first line to the second.
My guesses are that either I am getting confused about what the terms mean, the notation, the summation, or I have made an obvious mistake.

Either way, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FOIL (sry for my american lingo, lmk if youre not familiar with this acronym) the terms in the parens $((y_i-\bar{y}_U))-(\bar{y}_U-\bar{y}))$ and note that $\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}(y_i-\bar{y})=0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How exactly did statisticians agree to using (n-1) as the unbiased estimator for population variance without simulation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100041/how-exactly-did-statisticians-agree-to-using-n-1-as-the-unbiased-estimator-for)

Comment: I don't think it does? My issue was simply getting from the first line of this specific proof to the second, which was more of an algebra issue on my part.

Comment: This is an algebra FAQ (making it difficult to search for).  It has been asked here on CV several dozen times and always has the same answer: expand the sum and simplify using the fact that the sum of the residuals is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the intermediary step:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}(y_i-\bar{y})^2\right] & = \mathbb E\left[\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}((y_i-\bar{y}_U) - (\bar{y}-\bar{y}_U))^2\right]\\ &= \mathbb E\left[\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}(y_i-\bar{y}_U)^2 +n(\bar{y}-\bar{y}_U)^2-2(\bar{y}-\bar{y}_U)\underbrace{\sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}}(y_i-\bar{y}_U)}_{=  n(\bar{y}-\bar{y}_U)}\right] . 
\end{align}