# Significant difference between 2D spatial normal distributions

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution, spatial, chi-squared-distribution

My problem is as follows: I drop 40 equal balls at once from a certain point, a few meters over the floor. The balls roll, and comes to a rest. Using computer vision, I calculate the center of mass in the $X$-$Y$ plane. I have both large and small balls, heavy and light, dropped in separate experiments. Each 40-ball drop is conducted five times (five replicates) for each type of ball.
As mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65640/how-to-calculate-2d-standard-deviation-with-0-mean-bounded-by-limits) the balls will have a isotropic bivariate normal distribution in $X$ and $Y$ direction from their center of mass.
Now, how can I determine if a type of ball has a different radial distribution compared to another type of ball?

Some thoughts so far: Combining the $X$ and $Y$ distributions ($X^2+Y^2$) will give a chi-sqiuared distribution with two degrees of freedom [from here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65640/how-to-calculate-2d-standard-deviation-with-0-mean-bounded-by-limits).
In this case, this will be the same as the exponential distribution.
How do i compare these chi-squared distributions to determine if there is a significant difference?
Thanks for all help.

The original question is posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65640/how-to-calculate-2d-standard-deviation-with-0-mean-bounded-by-limits).
Many thanks to the people who have assisted there, but my problem has changed somewhat.

Comment: I seriously doubt the ball positions actually have a bivariate normal distribution: you should check the evidence for this. In any event, because you are studying only *radial* distributions, it appears you don't really have a spatial problem: you are merely comparing two *univariate* datasets (of radial displacements) to each other. The complication is that the $40$ observations in each dataset are clearly interdependent: not only must the mass-weighted vector sum of their locations be zero, any two balls must be separated at least by the sum of their radii.

Comment: Yes, if I study d = X^2+Y^2 (Chi-squared distribution/exponential distribution) or alternatively d = sqrt(X^2+Y^2) for every ball, it is of course no longer a normal distribution, and no longer a spatial problem. So, lets say I use the former Chi-squared approach. I now have a number of Chi-squared distributions for each replicate, which I want to determine if are significantly different from each other. A more detailed guide how to solve this is greatly appreciated.