# Hypothesis testing - significant differences in 2D spatial data

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution, data-transformation, spatial

This question is derived from a [previous post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71116/significant-difference-between-2d-spatial-normal-distributions), but the problem has changed somewhat and more information is provided here.

The challenge:
In an actual experiment, 40 dice are dropped into a body of water from a single point at the surface. They naturally diffuse as they sink through the water and settle on the floor of a tank.
We have three different types of die, small, medium and large. Naturally the large dice diffuse more and occupy a larger area on the bottom after settling.

Now, we can assume that the distribution of dice at the bottom have an isotropic normal distribution.
A light and a heavy dice drop of 50.000 dice have been simulated by:

```
N = 50000;
sigma = 1; % The diffusion, 1 for small dice and 3 for large dies to emphasize difference
x = (normrnd(0,sigma,N,1));
y = (normrnd(0,sigma,N,1));
pos = [x y];
r = sqrt(y.*y + x.*x);  % Calculate the distance from the centroid to each die
scatter(x,y);
hist(r,50);
hist(sqrt(r),50);
```

sigma = 1 and sigma = 3 produced the following two plots:
[image]

Now, I want to prove that the diffusion at sigma=1 is significantly different to sigma = 3. Of course, sigma will be unknown and a result of empirical observations. This can possibly be done by using the average radius r.

An idea:
The radial distribution looks like this:
[image]
This looks fine, but many tests such as ANOVA assume normality. Obviously, these plots are positive skewed. Applying a sqrt() transform yields this:
[image]

Would it now make sense to run a one-way ANOVA on the sqrt(r) data?
I find the sqrt() transform strange to use as r would never be normally distributed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As I recall the distribution of the radius of a two dimensional Gaussian with independent components is called a Rayleigh distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution). You might be able to find material on testing the $\sigma$ parameters for equality in two samples from the Rayleigh distribution. Good luck!