# Control charts constants computation

Tags: quality-control

The various control char constants are usually given for various population sizes, often up to 25.

I'd like to have more flexibility; is there à way to compute those instead?

Thanks

Comment: Please indicate which "constants" you are referring to.  (There are many, depending on the type of control chart.)  The answer is yes, these are computable; see the comment at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184034/estimating-process-standard-deviation-for-a-quality-control-chart-what-is-s-c#comment479639_184034 for instance.

Comment: Basically every constant used for any control chart. I'm creating a general purpose python library for SPC.

Comment: That would comprise an entire book on quality control, making your question overly broad to be answered here.

Answer (score 1):

There are several sources for such calculations.  Sadly, they tend to not all be published together.

One source is *Manual on Presentation of Data and Control Chart Analysis*, Dean V. Neubauer, Editor.  *Introduction to Statistical Quality Control* by D. C. Montgomery has most of the formulae you are looking for.

It may be easiest to check out a handful of books on the subject through your local library and see if you can piece everything together that you need.

On the bright side, you should almost never need a sampling plan that examines samples of more than 25 units at a time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. +1 for the "bright side". In fact, I already have the data points (and there might be a lot), but by reading you, I think I will consider raising a warning if we work with more than 25 points.