# What is the expected value and the mean of sample standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, expected-value

What is the expected value and the mean of sample standard deviation?
I know that I can derive the expectation and variance of sample variance using the $\chi^2$ pdf. But I don't know how to start with sample standard deviation.

Comment: The chi square only applies if you assume normality but you difn't state anything about distributions in your question. In the case of normality this question has been asked many times already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sample is IID normal then the answer is

$$ \sqrt{ \frac{2 \sigma^2}{n-1} }  \times \frac{ \Gamma(n/2) }{ \Gamma( \frac{n-1}{2} ) } $$

where $\sigma^2$ is the population variance and $n$ is the sample size. For a full derivation read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/why-is-sample-standard-deviation-a-biased-estimator-of-sigma).

Also, mean and expected value are the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I actually want to derive this . So can anyone else hinted me a starting point ?

Comment: Look at the link. It provides a full derivation, like I said in my answer.

Comment: @dhanushkaSampath, yw