# Question related to the sample standard deviation bias

Tags: estimation, standard-deviation

Let $ X_{1},...,X_{n} $ be a random sample of a population with finite variance. Prove that if $ \sigma^{2} > 0 $, then $ E(S_{n}) < \sigma $.

Based on [Zen's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/why-is-sample-standard-deviation-a-biased-estimator-of-sigma)

$0 \leq \mathrm{Var}(S_n) = \mathrm{E}(S_n^2) - \mathrm{E}^2(S_n)
    \;\;\Leftrightarrow\;\; \mathrm{E}^2(S_n) \leq \mathrm{E}(S_n^2)
    \;\;\Leftrightarrow\;\; \mathrm{E}(S_n) \leq \sqrt{\mathrm{E}(S_n^2)} =\sigma.$

From here we have that $ E(S_{n}) \leq \sigma$.

Using the condition $ \sigma^{2} >0 $, I can not see how to arrive at the strict inequality $ E(S_{n}) < \sigma $.

Comment: Isn't $\sigma$$^2$ = Var($S_n$)? If so the the equality on the far right is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelChernick $ \sigma^{2} $ is the variance of the population and Var($ S_{n}) $ is the variance of the statistic $ S_{n} $.

Comment: In that case what you did is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sigma > 0$ then $\mathbb{Var}(S_n) > 0$ so you can use the exact same reasoning but with strict inequality.

Comment: All variances are >=0. Since $\sigma$.>0 and Var($S_n$} approaches $\sigma^2$,  Var($S_n$)>0 for large enough n.