# When/why is the sqroot of the variance not a good estimator of the standard deviation?

Tags: variance, estimation, standard-deviation

From the (excellent) *Schaum's Outlines* for *Probability and Statistics* an example from the *Estimation Theory* chapter shows us that the typical estimation of the *variance* does provide an unbiased and efficient estimation of the true variance.  Yet the sqroot of that value is *not* so for the true standard deviation.  Then .. why?

[image]

Comment: The square root is a nonlinear operation, so being unbiased doesn't carry over from the variance to the SD.

Comment: Thx Nick - if you have further insight and/or references pls make an answer.

Comment: Similar recent [Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/428794/intuitive-explanation-of-expected-value-of-sample-standard-deviation/428934#428934). // For normal data the bias of $S$ estimating $\sigma$ is small for moderate sample sizes. // For very small sample sizes, 'control charts' for quality mgmt often use appropriate multiples of sample range.

Comment: @BruceET Thx - upvoted that one.

Comment: The idea that unbiasedness doesn't carry over from a variance estimate to an estimate of standard deviation is correct. But I don't see how this concept applies to efficiency here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the comment from @NickCox  I found this note on Wikipedia. We have that the `n-1` term does correct for the `variance` but the non-linear aspect of the square root allows for only partial correction on the `standard deviation`.  There is not a general way to get an unbiased estimate of the latter.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation

[image]