# Comparison of daily fitted volatility and observed absolute daily return

Tags: garch, volatility-forecasting

I am trying to estimate daily volatility of stock's return.

I have the below daily stock return data for 400 days:

```
 #create data
return<-structure(c(0.00083, -0.00574, -0.00857, 6e-05, -0.01347, 0.00184, 
                    0.01038, 0.00111, -0.00822, 0.00255, -0.00723, -0.00226, 0.01273, 
                    0.00345, -0.00027, 0.00964, 0.00933, 0.00171, 0.00088, -0.00687, 
                    0.00405, -0.00086, -0.00264, 0.00736, -0.00314, 0.00324, -0.00203, 
                    -0.00236, -0.01163, 0.01262, -0.0069, 0.01079, 0.00447, 7e-04, 
                    0.00853, -0.00071, 0.00312, 0.00107, 0.00174, -0.00403, 0.00247, 
                    -0.00102, -0.00213, -0.00403, 0.00171, -0.00637, 0.00186, -0.01382, 
                    0.0022, -0.00864, 0.00616, 0.00076, 0.00306, -0.00496, 0.00858, 
                    0.00845, 0.00878, 0.00347, -0.00712, 0.00871, 0.00108, -0.00103, 
                    0.00397, 0.00216, -0.00396, -0.00095, 0.00184, 0.00477, 0.00906, 
                    -0.00304, -0.00658, -0.00577, 0.00487, -0.00104, 0.00491, 0.00463, 
                    0.00353, 0.00282, -0.00026, -0.00144, -0.00714, -0.00401, 0.00637, 
                    -0.00763, 0.00789, 0.00332, 0.00243, 0.00207, -4e-04, -0.00169, 
                    0.00618, 0.00764, 0.00027, 0.00569, -0.00444, 0.00013, -0.00166, 
                    -0.00281, -0.00366, -0.00222, 0.0019, 0.00373, 0.00036, 0.00527, 
                    0.00028, -0.00559, 0.00535, 0.00125, 0.00781, -0.00037, -0.00352, 
                    -0.00131, -0.00329, 0.00276, -1e-05, 0.00363, -4e-04, 0.00071, 
                    -0.0082, -0.00554, -4e-04, -0.00142, -0.03342, -0.02079, 0.01411, 
                    -0.00592, 0.02127, -0.00025, -0.0145, -0.00036, -0.00431, -0.00553, 
                    -0.03135, 0.01845, -0.01748, -0.00658, 0.01555, 0.01079, 0.0105, 
                    -0.00634, 0.00558, 0.00624, 0.02099, -0.00251, -0.00924, -0.0199, 
                    -0.00148, -0.0076, 0.01054, 0.00222, -0.01678, -0.01832, 0.00304, 
                    -0.00658, 0.01541, 0.00326, 0.02271, -0.0022, 0.00815, 0.01088, 
                    -0.0329, -0.00152, -0.0236, 0.00176, -0.00036, 0.0054, -2e-04, 
                    -0.01927, -0.02099, 9e-05, -0.01552, -0.0159, -0.0208, -0.02749, 
                    0.0484, 0.00853, -0.00124, 0.00846, 0.00127, -0.02507, 0.03376, 
                    0.00699, 0.00965, 0.00409, 0.00451, -0.00015, -0.00527, 0.01066, 
                    0.00222, 0.00756, 0.0131, -0.01426, 0.0022, 0.00137, 0.00845, 
                    -0.00788, -0.00146, 0.01543, 0.00856, 9e-04, 0.00675, 0.0047, 
                    -0.00223, -0.0094, 0.00068, 0.00071, 0.01281, 0.00302, -0.00266, 
                    0.01082, 0.0015, 0.00178, -0.00353, 0.00639, 0.00123, -0.00079, 
                    -0.00054, -0.00283, 0.00687, -0.00389, -0.00113, -0.00655, -0.00816, 
                    -0.00213, 0.01456, 0.00295, 0.00693, -0.00087, 0.00497, 0.0037, 
                    -0.00013, -0.00295, 0.01079, -0.01916, -0.00084, 0.00716, -0.00466, 
                    0.00358, 0.00671, 0.0115, 2e-05, 0.00215, 0.00208, 0.00463, 0.00105, 
                    -0.00609, 0.00347, 4e-05, 0.00659, -0.00063, 0.00051, -0.00228, 
                    0.00158, 0.00101, 0.0088, -0.00219, -0.00037, 0.00467, 0.00107, 
                    0.00095, -0.00753, -0.00213, 0.00959, -0.00448, -0.01665, -0.00161, 
                    -0.00303, 0.00371, -0.02443, 0.00798, 0.00582, 0.00886, -0.00585, 
                    -0.00677, 0.00846, -0.00283, -0.01199, 0.00135, -0.00841, -0.00694, 
                    0.0021, -0.01328, -0.00277, 0.02121, 0.00813, 0.00612, 0.01044, 
                    0.00465, -0.00035, -0.00204, 0.00409, -0.00161, 0.00093, 0.00967, 
                    0.00298, 0.00943, -0.00126, -0.00173, -0.00954, -0.00123, 0.00382, 
                    0.00574, 0.00764, 0.00292, 0.00764, -0.00181, -0.00485, 0.00124, 
                    0.0045, 0.00228, 0.00461, 0.00018, -0.00341, -0.00655, 0.00358, 
                    -0.0062, 0.00282, 0.00682, 0.00468, -0.00528, 0.00736, -0.00162, 
                    -0.00258, -0.01095, -0.00904, -0.00731, -0.03023, 0.01293, 0.00077, 
                    0.01859, -0.00664, -0.01203, 0.01465, -0.02973, 0.00246, 0.01432, 
                    0.01203, -0.00795, 0.00821, -0.00051, -0.02629, 0.01092, -0.00321, 
                    0.00652, 0.01261, 0.00064, -0.00692, 0.01078, 0.01293, 0.00091, 
                    -9e-05, 0.00032, 0.0072, 0.00287, -0.00072, -0.00314, 0.00258, 
                    0.00034, 2e-05, -0.00491, -1e-04, -0.00845, 0.00614, -0.00243, 
                    -0.00533, 0.00503, -0.01233, -0.01807, 0.00794, 0.01412, -0.00449, 
                    -0.01568, 0.00906, 0.0064, 0.01088, -0.00139, 0.00991, -0.002, 
                    0.00276, -0.00393, 0.00685, -0.00358, 0.00284, 0.00192, 0.00406, 
                    0.00557, -0.00083, 0.00325, -0.00303, 0.00962, 0.0037, -0.00119, 
                    7e-04, 0.00273, 0.00256, -0.00196, 0.00156, 0.00071, 0.00084, 
                    0.00767), .Dim = c(400L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "return"), .Tsp = c(1, 
                                                                                             400, 1), class = "ts")
```

I am using rugarch package at R to estimate the daily volatility.

My code is as below:

```
library(rugarch)

#define the model
model_garch<-ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)), 
           mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = FALSE), 
           distribution.model = "norm")

#get the fitted values for volatility
fitv<-ugarchfit(model_garch,return)

fitted<-fitv@fit$sigma
```

So I get an GARCH(1,1) model fitted values. Then I want to compare mean of observed standard deviations(where here it is absolute value of returns) and mean of fitted values:

```
> mean(abs(return))
[1] 0.006292475
> mean(fitted)
[1] 0.008541654
```

But they are very different from each other. I tried a lot different models, but I got almost the same result. I wasn't expecting that. My expectation was for individual days observed and fitted may deviate from each other; but, at overall( for me their means) should close to each other.

Is my expectation wrong?
Or am I doing something wrong?
Or am I interpretting something wrong?

I think, I am missing a very fundemantel concept about volatility. I am stuck here. I will be very glad for any help or explanation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean(abs(return))` is not the mean of observed standard deviations, it is the mean of absolute returns. Daily standard deviations are not observable given only daily returns data. Try `sd(return)` for empirical standard deviation of returns. But even this is not quite what you need.

Your GARCH model assumes the mean is equal to zero. Then you should also use the same assumption when calculating the standard deviation for direct comparability. Use `sqrt(mean(return^2))` instead of `sd(return)`. But this is not quite what you need either.*

What you may reasonably expect given a decent GARCH model is that the average fitted conditional variance from the GARCH model, `mean(fitted^2)` will match the variance of the data calculated using the assumption of zero mean, `mean(return^2)`. **This** is the comparison to make.

*Note that if the GARCH model provides an unbiased fit of conditional variances, it need not provide an unbiased fit of conditional standard deviation (just as sample variance being an unbiased estimator of variance does not imply its square root is an unbiased estimator of standard deviation).

Comment: thanks a alot for the explanation. I am very surprised about, an unbiased variance estimator's square root doesn't imply an unbiased estimator of standard deviation. Is it possible to recommend an article or book to understand details of the reason. I want to understnad the details.

Comment: @oercim, you are welcome! This has been mentioned multiple times on Cross Validated, and there may be a dedicated thread explaining the phenomenon. I will see if I can find it. Just need to come up with the right keywords for the search, e.g. Jensen's inequality... And here you go: ["Why is sample standard deviation a biased estimator of $\sigma$?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/).

Comment: and I also want to ask your opinion about comparison of volatility models. Some softwares or packages uses "mean squares of deviations between conditional standart deviation estimates and absolute value returns(or square root of squared returns)".   So, I think, by impact of your explanation, it is better to use,  "mean squares deviations between conditional variance estimates and return squares" for volatility model comparisons.

Comment: Thank you very much for the the link.

Comment: @oercim, I am not sure about your last question. I would look up the literature on evaluation and comparison of volatility models, e.g. in Elliott & Timmermann's textbook ["Economic Forecasting"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691140131/economic-forecasting) (2016). There are some nontrivial points there that one has to be careful about. You may also ask this as a separate question.

Comment: thanks for your return. I will ask it at another question.