# Evaluation of Limit involved in the proof of Asymptotic Unbiasedness

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, asymptotics, unbiased-estimator, calculus

We know that $S^{2}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^{2}$ and $S$ is a biased estimator of $\sigma$. But if $n\rightarrow\infty$, then $S$ is an asymptotically unbiased estimator of $\sigma$. I found a proof [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/why-is-sample-standard-deviation-a-biased-estimator-of-sigma). But in the last step, instead of solving the limit, graphic visualization has been given. Can we somehow algebraically prove that bias$\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3759687/321264.

Comment: Yes, I was confused whether I should post in calculus or statistics. After initially posting on this channel and getting no replies. I thought it was more of a calculus based question rather than statistics. So, later I posted it on Math Stack exchange.

Comment: Is there a rule regarding which question can be posted where? I am new to Stack Exchange.