# Distribution of standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/631/standard-deviation-of-standard-deviation) addressed the normal distribution, but I am wondering what is known about the distribution of the standard deviation of a sample of size *n* drawn from an arbitrary distribution. In particular, what is the standard deviation of the standard deviation?

For a normal distribution, the s.d. of the s.d. is $\sigma \over{\sqrt{2n}}$. Is this approximately true for an arbitrary distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Answer (score 7):

A. van der Vaart gives derivation of assymptotic distribution of sample variance [in his book](http://books.google.com/books?id=UEuQEM5RjWgC&lpg=PR1&dq=asymptotic%20statistics&hl=fr&pg=PA27#v=onepage&q&f=false) as an example of [delta method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method). It would be not that hard (and very instructive) to adapt the derivation for the case of standard deviation.

Answer (score -7):

If the distribution has a mean and standard deviation, then I'd say yes.

Comment: We look for replies that provide support or at least references.  What are yours?

Comment: given that in the large sample limit, the central theorem applies, then I believe the suggested result holds. Can't be more of a help though...

Comment: Thanks; that's a good start.  There may be difficulties with distributions without fourth moments, though.