# Plain words (non-mathematical) explanation of the difference between Confidence Intervals, Standard Error of the Mean, and Standard Deviation?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, standard-error

As the question states, I'm interested in the difference between CIs, SEM, and SD, *explained in plain words* (so as to be able to communicate it to people without maths/stats background).

My current understanding (mainly gained through Googling around) is that:

- CIs indicate the reliability of a measurement
- SEM reflects the uncertainty in the (sample?) mean and its dependency on the sample size
- SD informs us about the spread of the population (i.e. SD reflects the variation of the data)

Is that correct?

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32318/difference-between-standard-error-and-standard-deviation and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6652/what-precisely-is-a-confidence-interval , you can also easily search the site for multiple similar threads.

Comment: Thank you for your input, Tim. However, none of the questions/answers you've linked to answer my question, which is about a plain explanation of the concepts (without assuming any prior knowledge of mathematics or statistics).

I also, of course, search for similar questions before I posted mine, but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I have edited the title to more closely indicate the intent of the question. A good answer to this question could easily have served as an answer to one of the existing questions, but I do think the "plain words" aspect might serve to differentiate it and I can imagine answers to the other questions being confusing to non-specialists. I also wonder if bundling CI, SD and SEM together makes it too broad, but on balance I think they are sufficiently closely related to make a combined question acceptable in scope. I'm, just, inclined to vote to leave this open.

Comment: CI does not imply reliability of measurement.Pl. understand statistics is different from psychometry. SEM attempts to assess uncertainty and not in a particular sample mean. SD tells spread of sample mean and not about population.

Comment: @subhash I think "SD tells spread of sample mean" needs some clarification: it measures the spread of the data about the mean, rather than the spread of the mean itself.

Comment: @Silverfish Your understanding is better. Thanks for clarification.