# Standard deviation of standard deviation of autocorrelated timeseries

Tags: standard-deviation, autocorrelation

I'm trying to get an estimate of the error in my sample standard deviation (not a statistician at all, hope I'm using correct terminology). The timeseries is normally distributed and follows an AR1 process to good enough approximation.

I understand how to do it without autocorrelation ([Standard deviation of standard deviation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/631/standard-deviation-of-standard-deviation)) and how to compute a correction for AR1 autocorrelation in an estimate of standard error for an estimate of the mean. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Correction_for_correlation_in_the_sample), but I'm uncertain whether I can just add this correction to the estimate of standard deviation of standard deviation.

(if you know of a reference, that would also be much appreciated)

Comment: Explicit simulation of an AR1 process leads me to believe you can indeed simply compute the standard deviation of standard deviation by this correction factor. Don't trust it completely and still looking for a reference...