# Follow-up to "Standard deviation of standard deviation"

Tags: estimation, standard-deviation

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/631/standard-deviation-of-standard-deviation) asks about a way to calculate the standard deviation of a standard deviation. The answer with most votes derives a formula for an unbiased estimator of $\text{SD}[s]$, which confuses me a bit, since $\text{SD}[s]$ denotes the standard deviation of the *sample standard deviation*. But then, what would an estimator for the standard deviation of the standard deviation be?

Comment: Because the sample standard deviation for a fixed sample size $n$ is a fixed multiple of the standard deviation, the result is self-evident.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. As you note the linked questions ask about the standard deviation of $s$, the sample standard deviation. Are you asking what the standard deviation of $\sigma$ is? In a typical frequentist perspective $\sigma$ is a fixed value. Therefore the variance and standard deviation are both 0. Can you clarify your question?