# Standard deviation of standard deviation under non-normality

Tags: variance, estimation, standard-deviation, variability

In [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/631/178794), an unbiased estimator for the standard deviation of the standard deviation **under normality** is provided.
I would be interested in such an estimator without the normality assumption, i.e., the standard deviation of the standard deviation for arbitrary distributions.

Comment: I believe such an estimator has been shown not to exist!

Comment: I see. It would be great if someone can provide a reference to Dave's statement.

Comment: Because the bias depends on (at least) the fourth moment of the distribution and there are many distributions with the same SD but different fourth moment, Dave's claim follows easily.

Comment: @whuber What if the 4th moment doesn’t exist?

Comment: @Dave I leave it to you to answer that question yourself, because we don't need to consider that possibility: the logic of my comment continues to apply when we limit the scope of "arbitrary distributions" to those with finite fourth moments.

Comment: @whuber Ok, but shouldn't it be possible to derive an estimator that takes the (sample) fourth moment (for distributions with finite fourth moments) into account to correct the bias introduced by the normality assumption?

Comment: See the discussion at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249688.